# pandas: reduce data frame to only specific chain of occurences

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have this data:

```
>>> data = {'event': [0,1,1,2,1,0],
...         'val1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
...         }
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['hash1', 'hash1', 'hash2',
                                      'hash3', 'hash3', 'hash3'])
>>> df1
       event  val1
hash1      0     1
hash1      1     2
hash2      1     3
hash3      2     4
hash3      1     5
hash3      0     6
```

What I want to do:
I want to reduce df to only show me data about those hashes, which have at least one occurence with **all** unique values of event.

so in the end I would get a dataframe looking like this:

```
       event   val1
hash3      2      4
hash3      1      5
hash3      0      6
```

I tried to split the dataframe to events either equal to zero vs bigger to zero and then tried to look up the indexes from the "equal to zero" dataframe in the "not equal to zero" dataframe - but I'm just really bad with pandas. If someone could help me accomplish this, I would be very grateful. 
Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the df prior to `groupby` on the index and then get the number of unique events using `nunique` and filter the orig df on the hashes that have more than a single unique entry:

```
In [62]:
gp = df1[df1['event'] !=0].groupby(level=0)['event'].nunique()
df1.loc[gp[gp> 1].index]

Out[62]:
       event  val1
hash3      2     4
hash3      1     5
hash3      0     6
```

breaking the above down:

```
In [63]:
df1['event'] !=0

Out[63]:
hash1    False
hash1     True
hash2     True
hash3     True
hash3     True
hash3    False
Name: event, dtype: bool

In [64]:
df1[df1['event'] !=0]

Out[64]:
       event  val1
hash1      1     2
hash2      1     3
hash3      2     4
hash3      1     5

In [65]:
df1[df1['event'] !=0].groupby(level=0)['event'].nunique()

Out[65]:
hash1    1
hash2    1
hash3    2
Name: event, dtype: int64

In [66]:
gp[gp> 1]

Out[66]:
hash3    2
Name: event, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

Based on your update you can compare the length of `nunique` values against the length of `unique` values of event:

```
In [107]:
df1.loc[df1.groupby(level=0)['event'].nunique() == len(df1['event'].unique())]

Out[107]:
       event  val1
hash3      2     4
hash3      1     5
hash3      0     6
```

Comment: thank you so much, I was actually only needing the last part
df1.loc[gp[gp> 1].index]
This helped me understand how to look up indexes from other dataframes.

Comment: Ah sorry - I just realized that's not 100% correct - this solution gives me the subset of indexes, which have at least more than one unique occurence, but I wanted the subset of indexes, which have ALL unique occurences in 'events'

Comment: Please edit your question, it's annoying to not clearly state your requirements